# Radare2 - How to save/restore metadata in debug session (BPs, flag, comments..)?

Tags: debugging, radare2

How can i save/reuse/preserve Radare2 metadata (BPs, comments, flags..) of a debug session for a new debug session? I restart the debugger alot and preserving environment would be very helpful.

I start with `r2 -d binary -r myenv.rr2 -i myscript.r2s`, create some flags, comments and such and then exit with `q`. `ood` usually is not enough (weird errors about fds and such. I quit completely most of the time). But if i try to load my project (`Po`) its asks me to restart the session and then i'm in a wrong context/process or something.

```
[0x7f7d020fb2c0]> Po myproject
Close current session? (Y/n) 
WARNING: module's base addr + delta is not a valid address
[0x7f8baef752c0]> dc
native-singlestep: No such process
Stepping failed!
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am currently trying to figure out how to persist comments between debug sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Commands starting with `P` is what you seek.

```
Usage: P[?.+-*cdilnsS] [file]  Project management
| P [file]          open project (formerly Po)
| P.                show current loaded project (see prj.name)
| P+ [name]         save project (same as Ps, but doesnt checks for changes)
| P- [name]         delete project
| P*                printn project script as r2 commands
| P!([cmd])         open a shell or run command in the project directory
| Pc                close current project
| Pd [N]            diff Nth commit
| Pi [file]         show project information
| Pl                list all projects
| Pn -              edit current loaded project notes using cfg.editor
| Pn[j]             manage notes associated with the project
| Ps [file]         save project (see dir.projects)
| PS [file]         save script file
| PS* [name]        print the project script file (Like P*, but requires a project)
| Pz[ie] [zipfile]  import/export r2 project in zip form (.zrp extension)
| NOTE:             the 'e prj.name' evar can save/open/rename/list projects.
| NOTE:             see the other 'e??prj.' evars for more options.
| NOTE:             project are stored in dir.projects
```

Example of save/restore session:

```
$ r2 -
[0x00000000]> f myflag = 0xdeadbeef
[0x00000000]> Ps myproject
[master (root-commit) cbcd6c2] default message
 Author: dacav <dacav@localhost>
 1 file changed, 687 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 rc.r2
[0x00000000]> q
```

Starting a new session:

```
$ r2 -
[0x00000000]> Pl
myproject
[0x00000000]> P myproject
[0x00000000]> f | grep myflag
0xdeadbeef 0 myflag
```

The project saving is done using `git`, as suggested by the `Ps` output.  I think using `git` is a great idea, and I like how `Pd` can tell what happened in a project over time.

Projects are saved under the directory pointed by the `dir.projects` configuration variable.

Also, the original question is quite old, and even trying `Po` will result in a deprecation warning these days.